# How to copy [UInt8] array to C pointer in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, c, arrays, swift, swift3

I'm trying to copy Swift `[UInt8]` buffer to a C pointer. I can't find the right solution, here is my code:

```
uploadBodyBytes = [UInt8]()
...
...
var data = crl.uploadBodyBytes[crl.bodyBytesUploaded..<crl.bodyBytesUploaded+actualLen]

_ = data.withUnsafeBytes({ (rawData /*provides UnsafeRawBufferPointer*/) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer in
    return memcpy(a, rawData /*expected UnsafeRawPointer*/, actualLen)
})
```

`data.withUnsafeBytes` gives me `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` but that seems to be incompatible with `memcpy` which expects `UnsafeRawPointer`.

Help appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be using memcpy in Swift. It's unsafe and clunky as hell. Instead, you should use `NSData` instead of `[UInt8]` to model a byte stream. It has built in initializers for making copies. If you show more context as to how you get these bytes and what you want to do with them, I can help you out.

Comment: I'm just trying to add some functionality to existing cURL Swift library. And they don't use Data (NSData) for some reason but [UInt8] buffers (and not even including Foundation library). I thought I should follow the way its already written. Not sure why memcpy should be so clunky?

Comment: Because it makes you work with unsafe, raw pointers

Answer (score 2):

You can access it with the [`baseAddress`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsaferawbufferpointer/2633273-baseaddress) property, but you don't need to.

Comment: See my edit. There really is no reason to be using memcpy in Swift :p

Comment: But I'm getting 'a' as a pointer in C callback function. let readFunc: curl_func = { (a, size, num, p) -> Int in ... not sure if simply a = rawData would work?

Comment: Oh true, I got mixed up. What's the initial source of this data, and what's the final destination? It's probably best to bind that UnsafeRawBufferPointer to some type, and create a Swift Array out of it.

Comment: I already have a Swift array of [Uint8] and I need to copy those bytes to 'a' which is C pointer ... eg. UnsafeMutableRawPointer?

Comment: Rather than first getting a pointer, then copying it, copy the Swift array first, then turn it into a pointer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129323/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-matej-ukmar).

Comment: True, but if you're using Metal and a buffer, you will need to copy it.